# Looping Through players inventory Steam PHP

Tags: php, backend, steam-web-api

Hello i was just Wondering if there was anyway to go through all the items in a

users inventory and echo the name of the item and the picture of the item,

Should i use rgInventory or rgDescriptions?

How should i go about looping through it?

Sorry im dumb

Comment: Please read through http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I would suggest reading through the provided docs for the api, making a good attempt at it, then coming back here if you can't do it, explaining what you have tried.

Comment: I have a perfect answer to you if you can wait

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get player steam id

**inventory:**
http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/steam_id/inventory/json/730/2

replace steam_id with your steam id
and 730 with appid

730 is csgo appid

[You find steam appid here](https://steamdb.info/apps/)

I recommend to get json formatter if you're using chrome

*scroll down your inventory and you see this*

**part of my inventory**

[image]

**Code**

```
//My steam inventory
$url =  "http://steamcommunity.com/id/tonzapvp/inventory/json/730/2";
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));

foreach($json->rgDescriptions as $value => $v){

    // we cant know what value $v is because its different everytime
    //that's why we are using '=>' after rgDescription

    $name = $v->market_hash_name;
    $icon_url = $v->icon_url;

   //http://cdn.steamcommunity.com/economy/image/$icon_url
   //echo this link in img src
    echo "<img src='http://cdn.steamcommunity.com/economy/image/$icon_url'>"
    echo $name;
}
```

Comment: Thanks really helped